# How to run a simple python http server as service

Tags: python, linux

This is my `script.py`:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler


class Serv(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            self.path = '/index.html'
        try:
            file_to_open = open(self.path[1:]).read()
            self.send_response(200)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            file_to_open = "Not Found!"
            self.send_response(404)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes(file_to_open, 'utf-8'))


httpd = HTTPServer(('0.0.0.0', 8000), Serv)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

And this is my `/lib/systemd/system/python.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=test
Documentation=test doc
[Service]
Type=notify
WorkingDirectory=/home/python
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/python/server.py
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
TimeoutStartSec=0
RestartSec=2
Restart=always
KillMode=process
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And when I run this command, it stuck and doesn't get me back the terminal:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start python
```

But I can  go to `http://ip:8000` and I can see my `index.html` content.

This is a simple web server I want to run it as a service (I don't want to run `python -m http.server 8000` for some reasons).

How can I run this script as a service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your `python.service` file:

```
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/python/script.py
```

`Type=notify` means that your service should notify with `READY=1` notification when it finish startup.